# How to speed up react app being sent to the client Azure

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azure

In my application i have the client in one folder and the server in another. I successfully deployed the application to azure web apps, this can be found at: https://wulfdevpage.azurewebsites.net/ However, it takes nearly 15 seconds for the page to respond and render the client, (this is just the basic react-app client for now, but ill build this out further soon.) my problem is simply that it takes way to long for the server to respond with the application.

here is my folder structure

```
--client
   - build
   // - (other parts of the react app)
--server
   - [other folders, like controllers, models etc.]
   - server.js //entry point
```

in my `server.js` file this is how the build folder is served up.

```js
// Set static folder
const __dirname = path.resolve();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/client/build")));
  app.get("*", (req, res) =>
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"))
  );
} else {
  app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("API is running...");
  });
}
```

This works, but again, it's taking nearly 15 seconds from the initial request to the client reaching my computer to make this work. I know a simple solution would be to just move the client to something like `azure static web apps` but I really don't want to go this route, I'd rather keep them all in one place for convenience's sake. There simply must be a quicker way to serve up the client.

Comment: What App Service tier are you using?

Comment: B1, but i had a production grade app using a higher tiered service that was acting in the same manner, for the company i am working for

Answer (score 0):

The major cause of performance of initial load issue is adding too many components into a single bundle file, so it takes more time to loading of that bundle files. To avoid this kind of issue, we need to structure our components in an optimized way.

To solve this react itself has a native solution, which is **code-splitting** and **lazy loading**. Which allows splitting bundle files into a smaller size. Refer [here](https://dev.to/nilanth/how-to-reduce-react-app-loading-time-by-70-1kmm)

The performance issue fix with some configuration changes. If you haven't done this already, please check below once

**Enable HTTP/2**

HTTP/2 brings major changes to our favorite web protocol, and many of the changes aim to improve performance and reduce latency on the web
[image]

**Turn Off the Application Request Routing Cookie**

Turn off the routing cookie in the Configuration blade to improve performance and resiliency.

[image]

**Keep the App Service Always On**

To prevent the idle shutdown, you can set the Always On flag in the App Service Configuration blade.
[image]

**Use local cache**

In App Setting create the app with a key of WEBSITE_LOCAL_CACHE_OPTION and a value of Always. You'll then have a d:\home folder pointing to a local cache on the machine and populated with a copy of your site content.

[image]

Use **App Service diagnostic** to fetch more details on the issue

Refer [here](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/nine-performance-tips-for-azure-app-services) for more info